# C# TIFF Multi-layer file

Tags: c#, photoshop, tiff, multi-layer

I usually use Adobe Photoshop to create "multi-layer" tiff files. I am not talking about multi-frame or multi-page tiff. They are layers above each other. Photoshop can save them, and later when I open them, I still can work with layers easily.

Is there any way to create and open "multi-layer" tiff files using .NET framework? When I open a multi-layer tiff using Bitmap class, I have 1 frame which has all the layers flattened. But at the same time, Photoshop can separate layers easily.

Comment: Very good question. I have the same problem (trying to read the layers). I don't know why somebody downvoted it.

Comment: @ValCool: thanks. it seems a question gets downvoted when no one knows the answer. I have some progress on my problem by using WANG Annotations. I can share with you if you want.

Comment: Does it read Photoshop's layered TIFFs? That's the most important for me. If you know the answer, feel free to post it under my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945059/read-photoshops-tiff-layers-with-libtiff-net